# When editing an existing document in React, Meteor Simple Schema validation on client side always returns 'true', despite invalid form data

Tags: mongodb, validation, meteor, reactjs, simple-schema

I have a form component in React that can be used to either save a new address, or edit an existing address object in MongoDB. I am using [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validating-data) for client-side schema validation (as well as server-side schema validation).

The document is being passed as a prop to the form with `shippingAddress`:

```
<ShippingAddressForm
    onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)} 
    shippingAddress={shippingAddress}
    editModeType={editModeType}
/>
```

In case of **New Address** mode type, `shippingAddress` is passed as a skeleton object:

```
shippingAddress = {
    firstName: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    zipCode: "",
    company: "",
    lastName: "",      
    address2: "",
    state: "",
    addressTypeSelected: "",
    country: "US",
    phoneNumber: ""
}
```

In case of **Edit Address**, `shippingAddress` is used to pass corresponding values from existing MongoDB document:

```
shippingAddress = {
    address: "Arcadia Bay Ct"
    city: "Delray Beach"
    company: "AT&T"
    country: "US"
    createdAt: Tue Aug 23 2016 11:59:13 GMT+0530 (IST)
    favorite: false
    firstName: "Max"
    label: "Arcadia Bay Ct"
    lastName: "Pricefield"
    phoneNumber: "987654321"
    state: "FL"
    userId: "WEwmG3iYgShasmzGT"
    zipCode: "33446"
}
```

Then the `ShippingAddressForm` inputs are populated using these values.

Before submitting the form, I validate the formData using a React handler. (This is being done via a submit button in a higher-level component, to which any state changes are regularly propagated.)

```
onSubmitHandler() {
    // get address from form
    // check it's complete and send error messages
    // if successful save and return to address book    
    const { userId, saveShippingAddress } = this.props;
    let formData = this.state.shippingAddress
    let invalidKeys,
        validityContext = AddressSchema.namedContext("shippingAddress");

    formData.userId = userId;
    formData.label = formData.address;
    AddressSchema.clean(formData);

    if(!validityContext.validate(formData)) {
      invalidKeys = validityContext.invalidKeys();
      invalidKeys =  _.map(invalidKeys, function (o) {
        return _.extend({message: validityContext.keyErrorMessage(o.name)}, o);
      });
      return toastr.error(invalidKeys[0].message, 'Error');      
    }
    return saveShippingAddress(formData);     
}
```

The validation in the above function works perfectly in case of a **New Address**. If any required key is missing, `validityContext.validate(formData)` returns `false` as it should.

However, in case of **Edit Address**, `validityContext.validate(formData)` always returns `true`, even if the data is invalid and required keys are missing etc.

I have checked the `formData` object being passed into the [.validate()](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validating-an-object) function, it is fine. It is not passing the old database object. If my form is missing a 'Last Name' field entry, then `formData` object is also missing a `lastName` key. But the SimpleSchema validator still returns `true` in edit mode.

I have also tried checking just one key using [.validateOne()](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validating-data). Same issue occurs there.

The same invalid data is then being caught in server-side validation check and error is returned. However, I need the client-side validation to work in all cases as well.

I am not using MongoDB modifiers.

Has anyone else faced this issue?